# Function Return with updated values

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was trying to sort list elements inside a function without return when I try to print the list by its name it does not get sorted, but it is sorted inside a function.

I have to update the list inside the function without returning

```
def sort(n):
    n.append(10)
    sorted(n)
n = [5,1,2,3]
print(n)
```

Expected : `[1,2,3,5]`
actual: `[5,1,2,3]`

Comment: You didn't call your `sort` function. Nor is it clear why you are appending `10` when you don't *want* to append `10`. Also, `sorted` doesn't work in-place.

Comment: once i called the function i have to update the list inside.

Comment: @DYZ: It isn’t. Maybe you’re thinking of `list.sort`?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry, I made a series of mistakes myself. It's a lesson for me too.

```
def isort(n):
    n.append(10)
    n.sort()  #I used n[:] = sorted(n), but it's superfluous.

n = [5,1,2,3]
isort(n)
print(n)

m = [7,9,3,13]
isort(m)
print(m)
```

output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 5, 10]
[3, 7, 9, 10, 13]
```

- `sort` is an existed fuction in python, need to change it to other name. I changed to `isort`.
- We have to call the function `isort` to let it do its work.
- We need to update the elements in the list to make the list update. `[:]` [Slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/509211/5403468) here.
- It's better to use different name between function argument and the call. (`n` and `m` here).

Many thanks to DYZ, Primusa, and Tomothy32 :)

Comment: Hi, the question states "I have to update the list inside the function without returning"

Comment: `sorted(n)` doesn't change `n`.

Comment: Why not just `n.sort()` instead of `n[:] = sorted(n)`?

Comment: @Tomothy32  Yeah... that's right. just call it inside. Thanks again :)

Comment: Also, I don't believe `sort` is a built-in - it's a member of `list`.

Comment: @Tomothy32  Then at first why `sort(n)` worked? Sorry I am justing wondering. I'm trying to find the answer in its [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/listobject.c) now. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: I don't know, but I can't find `sort`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html. I'm sure it's not a built-in, but instead a member of `list`.

Comment: @Tomothy32  Thanks for the link. Yeah, it's clear it isn't.